# Angular Renderer2 can't add class

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

`addClass` method of Renderer doesn't work in case element has class with binding

Some HTML

```html
<div addClassDir class="my-class-{{smth}}"></div>
```

Inside `addClassDir`

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'new-class');
}
```

I know that `class="my-class-{{smth}}"` is a not Angular way, but I don't know how people use my directive. It should work anyway, but it doesn't. What is the most correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are few correct ways to do that. It depends on what you want achieve.

1. HostBinding directive 
   https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding

```
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.valid') get valid() { return this.control.valid; }
  @HostBinding('class.my-class') myClass = true;
  @HostBinding('class') class = 'box';
}
```

2. NgClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
```

3. Attribute binding

```
<div [class.active]="isActive">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Renderer to add a class. Take advantage of `NgClass` syntax and the `HostBinding` directive.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2rmcfp)

```
export class MyDirective {

  @HostBinding('class.my-directive-class') customClass = true;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add your Component**

```
isTrueNewClass = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.isTrueNewClass = true;
}
```

**Adn your template**

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'new-class new-class2' : isTrueNewClass }">...</some-element>
```

**OR**

```
<div class="prevclass1 prevclass2" [ngClass]="{'new-class new-class2' : isTrueNewClass }">...</div>
```